# MySQL agrupar por mês e ano entre datas

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela chamda **agenda** em MySQL assim (a data está no banco de dados em formato date, coloquei no formato português apenas para ficar mais fácil o exemplo):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso de uma consulta que me listem os meses e ano que tenham datas cadastradas entre o dia_inicio e o dia_termino, no exemplo da tabela acima o que seria listado seria:

```
01/2020
02/2020
03/2020
04/2020
05/2020
07/2020
```

Reparem que o mês 06 de 2020 não aparece, pois não tem dias cadastrados nesse mês.

Tentei algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM agenda GROUP BY (BETWEEN agenda.dia_inicio AND agenda.dia_termino)
```

Sei que existe a função between, mas não é assim que se usa pelo visto. Como fazer?

Comment: Utilize um `GROUP BY YEAR(agenda.dia_inicio), MONTH(agenda.dia_inicio)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma.

```
SELECT * FROM agenda where (BETWEEN agenda.dia_inicio AND agenda.dia_termino) GROUP BY MONTH(dia_termino), DAY(dia_termino)
```

Answer (score 0):

A forma que você está fazendo não esta correto, priemiro o format da data deve ser "2020-03-03" (ANO-MES-DIA) para quer operações com data funcione. Depois se deve escolher uma coluna para se agrupar, até onde eu se não é possível agrupar por intervalo de datas, você deve fazer algo como:

```
SELECT * FROM agenda where (BETWEEN agenda.dia_inicio AND agenda.dia_termino) GROUP BY genda.dia_inicio
```

ou

```
SELECT * FROM agenda where (BETWEEN agenda.dia_inicio AND agenda.dia_termino) GROUP BY genda.dia_termino
```

Comment: A data está no formato certo, coloquei no formato português apenas para explicar. Mas no seu exemplo deu erro, o mesmo que o meu: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN agenda.dia_inicio AND agenda.dia_termino) GROUP BY agenda.dia_inicio'